# How is viscosity related to the forces in fluid?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, viscosity

I think it was that the forces are only perpendicular but do not know how this is related and from where it comes from.

EDIT: I am asking for the difference between viscous and non-viscous fluid in special relativity.

Comment: Are you referring to shear-thinning/thickening liquids (i.e. shear dependent viscosity), or just the constant viscosity (as in the answer by Gert)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand this, you need to understand to concept of *shear stress*. Consider the diagram below:

[image: Shear stress.]

In this diagram a bloc of viscous fluid is held between two parallel plates of surface area $A$ and with distance between the plates of $h$.

We now cause the upper plate to move at a constant speed $v$, while keeping the bottom plate perfectly still ($v=0$). To achieve this we need to apply a force $F$ to overcome the viscous drag forces in the fluid. The latter can be best understood to be the friction forces between thin, parallel layers of the bloc of fluid.

The force $F$ can be expressed as so-called *shear stress* $\sigma$:

$\large{\sigma=\frac{F}{A}}$.

According to Newton:

$\large{\sigma=\mu\frac{dv}{dh}}$ (Eg.1), where $\mu$ is the so-called *shear viscosity* and $\frac{dv}{dh}$ the *shear rate*.

When liquids flow (e.g. through pipes) shear rate arises, which in turn cause shear stress (acc. Eq.1). The shear stress can then be related to practical observables like the pressure required to make a certain fluid flow through a certain pipe at a specified flow rate.

Comment: http://imgur.com/8j9Ps5X Is it because of F(all) that the fluid is movung slower?

Comment: @Blake: the friction forces, which act parallel to the flow lines, need to be overcome by a force in the opposite direction, otherwise the flow would simply halt. This force is supplied (in the case of pipe flow) by the pressure difference at the inlet (higher pressure) and outlet (lower pressure).

Comment: The little cubes are the particles and the line is A. My question is "Is liquid with low viscosity frictionless (there is not F fric)?"

Comment: @Blake: liquids always have *some* viscosity but obviously some have very low viscosity (liquid helium e.g.) and some very high viscosity (bitumen e.g.). The lower the viscosity, the lower the drag forces, to the point where they might me negligible compared to inertial forces (gravity e.g.).

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is not set correctly but I want to know how viscosity affects the forces between particles. Thank you for the patience.

Comment: @Blake: you cannot calculate the forces between the particles from viscosity because $\mu$ is a *stochastic* (bulk) property. High viscosity strongly suggests strong interaction between the particles. Fluid mechanics however does not tell you about intra-molecular forces, that is not its approach.

Comment: I am talking in the context of special relativistic fluid and how no viscosity changes the forces and the interaction between particles.

Comment: @Blake: I don't know anything about a *special relativistic fluid* but even in that case I expect the viscosity to *arise from* interaction between particles and not the other way around.

Comment: @Blake If you are familiar with statistical mechanics, viscosity arises from translational non-equilibrium and is a macroscopic quantity only. It makes no more sense to talk about the viscous force between particles as it does to talk about the temperature or pressure of a single particle. These things can only be defined over an ensemble of particles.

Comment: Then what is the difference between fluid with viscosity and non-viscous fluid in special relativity?

Comment: @Blake: to be honest, I don't know.

Comment: I have read some papers since this question arises and come up with the answer that if the fluid is viscous the net force between two particles in not perpendicular to their interface (if we consider particles as cubes with length l->0).